# 360 controller sticking in 3rd person view

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I'm playing Skyrim.
I put it in  first person view and as soon as I start walking around it jumps back to 3rd person.
I've tried s1st,tfc,epc in console commands but nothing is working
 **I want to play in 1st person view.** What do I do?

Comment: Do you have the toggle first/third person control binded to the stick you use to walk? Perhaps your joystick is having some issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known glitch that appears after acquiring the Dawnguard expansion. There does not appear to be an easy way to fix it apart from possibly uninstalling the downloaded expansion.

As pushasha said in the comments: You can use [this mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/22620) to fix the issue.